# How can i save canvas image as a png in my pc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I want to save the image canvas made in my pc, i've already searched how to do this, but i only see HTML related stuff.

Code Example:

```
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');
let canvas = createCanvas(200, 200)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

// Write "Awesome!"
ctx.font = '30px Impact'
ctx.rotate(0.1)
ctx.fillText('Awesome!', 50, 100)

// Draw line under text
var text = ctx.measureText('Awesome!')
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.lineTo(50, 102)
ctx.lineTo(50 + text.width, 102)
ctx.stroke()

// Draw cat with lime helmet
loadImage('Templates/Question.png').then((image) => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 50, 0, 70, 70)
  //Save code here.
})
```

Comment: right click -> save image as

Comment: [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)